# What is the maximum possible current that can mains supply can deliver?

Tags: ac, mains, generator

This question has been bugging me for a while. I know that theoretically its like - infinity to + infinity and it depends on the load that is connected to the mains supply plus the load at which the fuse/circuit breaker can handle max.

Lets take an example.Assume that I bypass the power meter and everything and directly connect to the pole utility. Will my current ability increase as I connect a bigger cable to draw more and more current? What will be the max current is possible to be drawn?Is it limited by the max current capability of the utility transformer?

Also what could be the max current at the source of generation of electricity(lets take an example of the generator at nuclear power plant, its not infinite anyway as it could handle only a particular amount of current )?Thanks in advance everyone. Cheers :)

Comment: can you please structure your question a little more? A paragraph or two (a paragraph can be made by inserting empty lines between a logical section) would really help the readability!

Comment: @Marcus sorry for the cluttering.

Comment: also, your question is (unintentionally) incredibly broad. The answer is that you would have to know the immediate current draw of every "tap" on your local sub-grid; then you'd need to compare that to the total generating capacity of all connected, active (or activatable) generation plants.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB well, I think a wiki answer would work quite fine, wouldn't it? like: things that limit your current (bullet point list). It would grow very long very quickly. So, yeah, as is, this question is too broad.

Comment: In addition, if you're not connecting directly to a major "high tension" line, then you'll be limited by the current-carrying capacity of the transformer that you're connected through.

Comment: Thanks. So the current at the generating station (source of current:generator via turbine here) should be in millions or billions of amperes right?

Comment: @RahulSalin hm, you said you know that "theoretically" you understand the current should be infinite. But I say: NOPE. Even theoretically, we teach people that real world voltage sources have an *internal resistance*. You know that, right?

Comment: @Marcus Muller Yes I saw that on many forums as well as wiki and thats what made me confused. It can never be infinite, if it where the whole country would just need on generating station.

Comment: @RahulSalin actually, we now have a "distributed grid," there are even some homes with only 3-4KW of generating capacity that function as "generating stations", and large hydro-dams that have up to several GW of capacity.

Comment: @Robherc KV5ROB So, I guess if the generator just had a short circuit its gonna be pretty scary!

Comment: I know that they step up the voltage to 300Kv and more but no where do they mention about currents that is why I asked this question.

Comment: Generators are required to have safeties in place to disconnect them from the grid & shut-down in case of any overload.

Comment: Yes they would else it would be catastrophic. But its there max current I wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, it is scary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9PUVQaeI0k<-- that was probably but a normal household copper cable shorting that high voltage line . The transformers and the power plant won't even notice the increase in current flow this "small" spark means.

Comment: That arc. That is the scariest and the noise it makes. Have seen a guy in my college do a smaller version with a microwave trans.

Comment: Here's a link you can get started on if you're really serious about getting your answer [North American Interconnects](https://energy.gov/oe/services/electricity-policy-coordination-and-implementation/transmission-planning/recovery-act-0) From here, you can find the interconnect that supplies your area (if you're in North America). Then, you can find the website for your interconnect. Every interconnect I've checked on publishes historical charts of potential generation vs. actual load used. This will give you an idea of how much "excess capacity" your interconnect has available.

Comment: @robherc I'm not sure if excess capacity really answers it. An ordinary line might have ~100A/phase capacity, but fault current approaching 10kA. OPs question is probably too broad to properly answer.

Comment: @rahul This doesn't completely answer your question, but when a friend was doing some power generation work, the very first breaker on the generator bus was set to trip at ~200A, but was apparently rated to carry 10kA (or maybe 20kA? I can't remember) for the 30s it took the breaker to open. The arc flash danger sticker for that bus was something ridiculous like 100+ft

Comment: @mbrig I know it's not a complete answer, that's why I only gave it to him in a comment. As the question ends up being soo broad as it's stated, it becomes mostly "academic," so I pointed him to a resource to start research & potentially be able to narrow down his desired answer with ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this question as "unclear". Do you want to know the maximum rating currently used on earth, what currently limits the grid or what's necessary to construct a grid (generator, power lines, transformers) that delivers twice, thrice, ... the power? So is your question on "applied" current laws (P = I x V) or how the grid currently limits the maximum available power. This might be an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - asking for limits while wanting to know how the grid from plant to socket works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is not infinity, even 'theoretically'.

There are at least 3 defined currents for any point on the supply, and that point can be anywhere from the terminals of a nuclear power station, down through transformers and transmission lines, right to the socket on your wall.

1) Rated current

This is the maximum current it's designed to deliver, 24/7, without overheating. All upstream components are designed to carry this indefinitely.

2) Minimum fault current

This is the minimum current that should flow if you short circuit the output. It is designed to be big enough to open fuses 'quickly', before thermal damage occurs to upstream wiring. It's often used to define the minimum resistance of safety earth bonding, so that in the event of a line to chassis fault, enough current will flow to open the live breaker. It's no good have a (let's say) 10 ohm ground connection, that just sits there and cooks in the event of a short to ground, while failing to open the breaker.

3) Maximum fault current

This is the maximum current that should flow if you short circuit the output. It is designed to be small enough to not damage up stream wiring while the breakers open, and to specify how much current the breakers should be able to stop successfully when choosing the breakers for that link. Damage could occur thermally, or on big feeders through Lorentz forces tearing them out of mountings. This is achieved by having a high enough impedance in the upstream wiring and through transformers, both their resistance and their leakage inductance. Distribution transformers are installed to a minimum impedance specification. It often has to be increased locally to protect areas of the grid.

Obviously there is an economic tradeoff here. A high impedance supply will generate lower fault currents (easier to protect), but will lose more power in line resistance, and have more voltage drop with varying load. The cost of the supply rises as its quality rises, which is kinda what you'd expect.

It is necessary to have a defined maximum fault current, because short circuits *will* happen, and replacing installed cable and transformers is far more expensive than replacing breakers. Lightning strikes can initiate arcs, and I once had a very entertaining grandstand view of a digger putting its backhoe through an 11kV feeder on an adjacent building site. Our lights dimmed for about one second before going out, a puff of smoke rose from the hole, as he tripped the breaker to the entire business park.

Answer (score 2):

An example: http://www.power-technology.com/projects/drax/

> [The generators] generate 19,000A at 23,500V. A transformer increases the voltage to 400,000V before sending it via cables to the National Grid sub-station for distribution.